# MapReduce - Reduce is not called

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I've been trying to run this project which I found in internet and altered for my intention.

Map function is called and works properly, I checked the results from console. But reduce is not getting called

First two digits are key and rest is value.
[image]

I've controlled the match between map output and reduce input key,value pairs, I've changed them many times, tried different things but couldn't get a solution.

Since I'm a beginner in this topic probably there is a small mistake. I wrote an other project and had the same mistake again "reduce is not called"

I also tried to change output valu class of reduce to IntWritable, TextWritable instead of MedianStdDevTuple and configured the job but nothing changed.

I don't need the solution only, want to know the reason as well. Thanks.
here is the code

```
package usercommend;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;

import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;
import org.apache.htrace.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import usercommend.starter.map;


public class starter extends Configured implements Tool {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{
        int res =ToolRunner.run(new starter(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Job job=Job.getInstance(getConf(),"starter");
        job.setJarByClass(this.getClass());

        job.setMapperClass(map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(reduces.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(MedianStdDevTuple.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;

    }

    public static class map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text,IntWritable, IntWritable> {
        private IntWritable outHour = new IntWritable();
        private IntWritable outCommentLength = new IntWritable();
        private final static SimpleDateFormat frmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void map(LongWritable key , Text value,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            //System.err.println(value.toString()+"vv");
            Map<String, String> parsed = transforXmlToMap1(value.toString());
            //System.err.println("1");
            String strDate = parsed.get("CreationDate");
            //System.err.println(strDate);
            String text = parsed.get("Text");
            //System.err.println(text);
            Date creationDate=new Date();
            try {
            //  System.err.println("basla");
                 creationDate = frmt.parse(strDate);
                    outHour.set(creationDate.getHours());
                    outCommentLength.set(text.length());
                    System.err.println(outHour+""+outCommentLength);
                    context.write(outHour, outCommentLength);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.err.println("catch");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

            //context.write(new IntWritable(2), new IntWritable(12));
        }

        public static Map<String,String> transforXmlToMap1(String xml) {

            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            try {
                String[] tokens = xml.trim().substring(5, xml.trim().length()-3).split("\"");

                for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length-1 ; i+=2) {
                    String key = tokens[i].trim();
                    String val = tokens[i+1];

                    map.put(key.substring(0, key.length()-1),val);
                    //System.err.println(val.toString());
                }
            } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.err.println(xml);
            }
            return map;
        }
    }

    public static class reduces extends Reducer<IntWritable, IntWritable, IntWritable, MedianStdDevTuple> {

        private MedianStdDevTuple result = new MedianStdDevTuple();
        private ArrayList<Float> commentLengths = new ArrayList<Float>();
        Log log=(Log) LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

        @Override
        public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            System.out.println("1");
            log.info("aa");
            float sum = 0;
            float count = 0;
            commentLengths.clear();
            result.setStdDev(0);

            for(IntWritable val : values) {
                commentLengths.add((float)val.get());
                sum+=val.get();
                ++count;        
            }

            Collections.sort(commentLengths);

            if(count % 2 ==0) {
                result.setMedian((commentLengths.get((int)count / 2 -1)+
                            commentLengths.get((int) count / 2)) / 2.0f);
            } else {
                result.setMedian(commentLengths.get((int)count / 2));
            }

            double avg = sum/commentLengths.size();
            double totalSquare = 0;
            for(int i =0 ;i<commentLengths.size();i++) {
                double diff = commentLengths.get(i)-avg;
                totalSquare += (diff*diff);
            }

            double stdSapma= Math.sqrt(totalSquare/(commentLengths.size()));
            result.setStdDev(stdSapma);
            context.write(key, result);
        }
    }
}
```

sample input

```
<row Id="2" PostId="7" Score="0" Text="I see what you mean, but I've had Linux systems set up so that if the mouse stayed on a window for a certain time period (greater than zero), then that window became active.  That would be one solution.  Another would be to simply let clicks pass to whatever control they are over, whether it is in the currently active window or not.  Is that doable?" CreationDate="2010-08-17T19:38:20.410" UserId="115" />
<row Id="3" PostId="13" Score="1" Text="I am using Iwork and OpenOffice right now But I need some features that just MS has it." CreationDate="2010-08-17T19:42:04.487" UserId="135" />
<row Id="4" PostId="17" Score="0" Text="I've been using that on my MacBook Pro since I got it, with no issues.  Last week I got an iMac and immediately installed StartSound.PrefPane but it doesn't work -- any ideas why?  The settings on the two machines are identical (except the iMac has v1.1b3 instead of v1.1b2), but one is silent at startup and the other isn't...." CreationDate="2010-08-17T19:42:15.097" UserId="115" />
<row Id="5" PostId="6" Score="0" Text="+agreed.  I would add that I think you can choose to not clone everything so it takes less time to make a bootable volume" CreationDate="2010-08-17T19:44:00.270" UserId="2" />
<row Id="6" PostId="22" Score="2" Text="Applications are removed from memory by the OS at it's discretion.  Just because they are in the 'task manager' does not imply they are running and in memory.  I have confirmed this with my own apps.&#xA;&#xA;After a reboot, these applications are not reloaded until launched by a user." CreationDate="2010-08-17T19:46:01.950" UserId="589" />
<row Id="7" PostId="7" Score="0" Text="Honestly, I don't know.  It's definitely interesting though.  I'm currently scouring Google, since it would save on input clicks.  I'm just concerned that any solution might get a little &quot;hack-y&quot; and not behave consistently in all UI elements or applications.  The last thing I'd want is to not know if I'm focusing a window or pressing a button :(" CreationDate="2010-08-17T19:50:00.723" UserId="421" />
<row Id="8" PostId="21" Score="3" Text="Could you expand on the features for those not familiar with ShakesPeer?" CreationDate="2010-08-17T19:51:11.953" UserId="581" />
<row Id="9" PostId="23" Score="1" Text="Apple's vernacular is Safe Sleep." CreationDate="2010-08-17T19:51:35.557" UserId="171" />
```

Comment: It's hard to help you if we don't know what your input file looks like

Comment: @Cricket_007 I'm getting the correct result from input file so i don't know why you need to know input file. Program is writing correct key-value pairs in map function.

Comment: Because maybe I wanted to try running the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You took [this code](https://github.com/adamjshook/mapreducepatterns/blob/master/MRDP/src/main/java/mrdp/ch2/MedianStdDevDriver.java)? I'm guessing the problem is that you did not set the correct inputs and outputs for the Job.

Here is what you are trying to do based on your class definitions.

- Map Input: `(Object, Text)`
- Map Output: `(IntWritable, IntWritable)`
- Reduce Input: `(IntWritable, IntWritable)`
- Reduce Output: `(IntWritable, MedianStdDevTuple)`

But, based on your Job configuration

```
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(MedianStdDevTuple.class);

job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
```

It thinks you want to do this

- Map Input: `(Object, Text)` -- I think it's actually `LongWritable` instead `Object`, though, for file-split locations
- Map Output: `(IntWritable,`**`MedianStdDevTuple`**`)`
- Reduce Input: `(IntWritable, IntWritable)`
- Reduce Output: `(`**`Text`**`,`**`IntWritable`**`)`

Notice how those are different? Your reducer is expecting to read in `IntWritable` instead of `MedianStdDevTuple`, and the outputs are also of the incorrect class, therefore, it doesn't run.

---

To fix, change your job configuration like so

```
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(MedianStdDevTuple.class);
```

---

Edit: Got it to run fine and the only thing I really changed outside of the code in the link above was the mapper class with this method.

```
public static Map<String, String> transforXmlToMap1(String xml) {

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    try {
        String[] tokens = xml.trim().substring(5, xml.trim().length() - 3)
                .split("\"");

        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length - 1; i += 2) {
            String key = tokens[i].replaceAll("[= ]", "");
            String val = tokens[i + 1];

            map.put(key, val);
            // System.err.println(val.toString());
        }
    } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.err.println(xml);
    }

    return map;
}
```

Comment: thanks for help, i changed object to longwritable as you said and still not working. i will share a sample input.

Comment: Are you able to run a simpler example with a reducer? Like a simple word count?

Comment: yes, I'm, in an other project. But I couldn't be able to run reduce method in this project.

Comment: do you have any other idea about question?

Comment: Sorry it took me so long, but I was able to run this code that I linked to at the top of my answer fine, then I used your sample input and I saw that one reducer was ran. I am using the Cloudera 5.5 VM.

Comment: Problem was solved a few days ago. There was a sneaky mistake about catch(). Since I didn't write this code, I couldn't forecast where to focus in code to find issue. This is what catch() used to be catch( ParseException e) and program was giving nullexception but nothing was appearing. As soon as changed it to Exception e instead of ParseException I got the error and changed the code by adding a control statement. Evetything seems ok now. Since your answer is correct and I didn't answer my own question I consider your answer accepted.Thanks

Comment: this is my latest question you may want to check this as well.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142079/java-net-connectexception-connection-refused-8020-failed