# Connection refused to quickstart.cloudera:8020

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera, bigdata

I'm using Cloudera-quickstart 5.5.0 virtualbox

Trying to run this on terminal. As you can below, there is an exception. I've searched for solution to solve this on internet and found something.

1-) configuring core-site.xml file. https://datashine.wordpress.com/2014/09/06/java-net-connectexception-connection-refused-for-more-details-see-httpwiki-apache-orghadoopconnectionrefused/

But I can only open this file readable and haven't been able to change it. It seems I need to be root or hdfs user (su hdfs -) but it asks me for a password which I don't know.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you start HDFS from Cloudera Manager?

Comment: I'm not sure. Can you explain more details?

Comment: Click "Launch Cloudera Express" icon on the Desktop. You need to be running HDFS order for `hadoop fs` to work and you need Zookeeper and YARN running to even run Mapreduce code.

Comment: Also, you might get a warning that you need 8 GB RAM on the virtual machine to start... I think that the default of 4 GB is fine if all the services aren't started

Comment: when i launch it, it's  giving warnings and nothing happens. I will add the picture of it in question

Comment: If it gives you the above warning I mentioned, then it also tells you how to fix it with a `force` option

Comment: vm has 4096 mb ram currently

Comment: Assuming you have enough RAM on your computer, then just follow the instructions in the warning there. Otherwise, run the command shown with the force option

Comment: i added another picture which shows what happened when i tried to run the command

Comment: the messages are descriptive... "You must specify --express"

Comment: I did what you said and still having the 8020 issue. Do you think I should configure core-site.xml(8020 to 9000) or something. I'm able to open core-site.xml only readable so  I can't modify this file.

Comment: You don't need to modify any configurations in the quickstart VM

Answer (score 2):

A network configuration is not your problem. You don't need to touch any configurations in the VM, you need to start the services. In this image, for example. The HDFS service on the left is disabled, and I get the same error on that last command.

[image: services]

You have to start Cloudera Manager **and** start ZooKeeper, YARN, and HDFS (in that order).

To open Cloudera Manager, go to `http://quickstart.cloudera:7180` in Firefox on the VM.

[image: CM]

Then start the mentioned services.

[image: start zk]

After you start the services, you can use HDFS commands.

[image: hdfs dfs ls]

Comment: thanks for answet.I'm trying to run cloudera manager but it's working so slow. Is this normal?

Comment: Well, you gave 4GB of RAM to the VM, so if your computer barely has any more than that available, then yes, that is normal